# spell check for a sentence using textblol

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm trying a create a custom spell-check function with Textblob for sentence,were I'm unable to print whole corrected sentence

Input:

```
def spellcheck(sentence):
    correct_sentence=[]
    
spell_check=TextBlob(sentence)
    for words in spell_check.tokens:
        corr_spelled=words.correct()
        correct_sentence.append(corr_spelled)
        query=" ".join(correct_sentence)
        return query
```

Output:

```
spellcheck("what are is caled airoplance")
```

Answer:

```
what
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the following:

```
from textblob import TextBlob 
  
sentence = TextBlob(sentence) 
  
correct_sentence = sentence.correct() 
  
print(correct_sentence )
```